# How to make transparent modal VC?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have two VC. On the second VC I have a color rectangle. VC has transparent background. When the second is called the VC (by clicking a button with *Modal* action), there is a rectangle, as conceived, VC has a transparent background. But it's not for long time, until the end of the second appearance of the VC. When the animation ends with the appearance of the second VC, the VC of the second background is black. How to make a transparent background of the second VC after animation?

Comment: View controllers don't have backgrounds, views do.  Instead of putting up a new view controller, try making your rectangle view part of the first controller and using its `hidden` property.

Comment: Good idea, thanks! But how make modal view as I described?

Comment: You could modify MJPopupViewController to satisfy your needs https://github.com/martinjuhasz/MJPopupViewController

Comment: Thanks for this info. Do you know something about swift compatibility with this framework?